# Regarding User authentication on Azure SQL

Tags: authentication, azure, azure-storage, azure-worker-roles

I would like to store username,password and his/her accessible container with permission on Azure sql.Is it best practice or are they any best practice to be followed.

What i need to acheive is creating simple user store possibly in the blob storage and then create a mapping between the user id and the default container and the access will be limited to that. Doing this as a provider so the implementation can be changed any time.

Also have a provision for an admin user which can look across all the container per storage account.

Note:Having this is Azure worker role.

Need your inputs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you looked at using Windows Azure Access Control Service? It provide for authentication, and would keep you from having to reinvent the wheel. There are a lot of moving parts to building out a auth system in SQL Server, and it probably isn't a strategic part of your system.

Also, look at using ASP.NET Authorization, that should provide the plumbing for you if ACS doesn't meet your needs.